# TinyMCE: Using CSS class attributes with the formatselect-dropdown formats

Tags: javascript, richtextbox, tinymce, richtextediting

I would like to customize [the formats](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/theme_advanced_blockformats) in the TinyMCE [formatselect dropdown](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Control_reference) to support css class attributes.

Example: If would like to be able to select `<h2 class='foo'>` instead of just `<h2>` as format in the formatselect dropdown.

Does anyone here have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no smart way to do this in the current TinyMCE version [according to its main developer](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/punbb/viewtopic.php?id=15914):

> We have plans for a advanced style
>   format plugin. So that you can specify
>   formats, styles, containers, wrappers
>   etc in a JSON style structure.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Spocke - Main developer of TinyMCE

...though there is an "unsmart" way to achieve this:

A CSS-class `h2.foo` defined in TinyMCE's `content_css` will appear in the [styleselect dropdown](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Control%5Freference) as *foo*.

You can now select a `<h2>`-text and choose the style *foo* from the styleselect dropdown. This results in `<h2 class='foo'>`.