# Add class to h1-tag (into formatselect) - TinyMCE / Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I would like to add a class to my "formatselect" options of the tinyMCE in Wordpress. So when selecting a h1 from the dopdown it should generate a `<h1 class="blue">`.

I found [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781549/tinymce-using-css-class-attributes-with-the-formatselect-dropdown-formats), but can't get it to work.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is described there is working even though not suitable for everyone. I'll give you a short list of what you need to do:

**1. use the [content_css](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE%3aConfiguration/content_css) tinmce init setting**

```
content_css: "http://www.mydomain.com/css/content.css",
```

**2. Create a content.css file containing your class**

```
h1.foo {
    background-color: #F067A0;
}
```

**3. use the styleformatting tinmce init setting**

```
style_formats: [{
  title: 'My Foo styles'
  }, {
 title: 'Foo',
  block: 'h1',
  classes: 'foo',
  exact: true
,
```

**4. Make sure you have the style button included (tinymce init)**

```
theme_advanced_buttons1: "styleselect",
```

You should be able to select text from the h1-tag in the editor and select foo from the dropdown menu of styles. The class should be applied to your selected text.

Comment: glad to have been able to help